# How to write a reference to an array of 10 integers without using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, reference

Sorry if this is a really dumb question, but for some reason I can't understand how to do it.

I tried to write code that makes the most sense for me, but it's not working:

```
int numbers[10]{};

int& numbers_ref  { numbers };   // nope
int  numbers_ref& { numbers };   // nope 
int& numbers_ref  { &numbers };  // nope
int  numbers_ref& { &numbers };  // nope
```

Edit: I tried using `[]` but I still couldn't get it working without using `auto`:

```
int& numbers_ref[]  { numbers };   // nope
(int  numbers_ref[])& { numbers };   // nope 
(int numbers_ref[10]) &  { numbers };  // nope
int []numbers_ref& { &numbers };  // nope
```

The only way I can get a reference is what **P0W** said:

```
auto& numbers_ref= numbers;  // yay
```

P.S. Thank you **chris**, this is *exactly* what I wanted, but couldn't guess the syntax:

```
int (&numbers_ref)[10] = numbers;  // exactly right!
```

Comment: If `numbers_ref` is supposed to be a reference to an *array* of 10 integers, then how come you're not using `[]` in declaring it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef int numbers_type[10];
numbers_type& numbers_ref = numbers;
```

**Edit:** (As suggested by chris)

```
int (&numbers_ref) [10] = numbers; // If you don't want typedef
```

In C++11 :

```
auto& numbers_ref= numbers;
```

Comment: Or just `int(&numbers_ref)[10]` if you don't want the type alias.